# What wood is our floor made from and will it be good as polished boards?

Tags: wood, floor

Can anyone tell what wood this is.

It is a photo underneath the house (*Southern Australia region*).

Will that come up well as a wooden floor?

[image: picture of wood floor under house]

Comment: You might get a better identificastion in woodworking. most any hardwood looks good polished, and that looks like some kind of hardwood to me.

Comment: Cool thanks @Jasen for the feedback and I'll try asking the woodworkers.

Comment: Actually, "wood identification" is off topic at [woodworking.se] because it's incredibly difficult to do from a picture on the internet. That said, it looks like it may well be the original T&G wooden flooring that was later covered by carpet/whatever. It _is_ a very nice looking floor and a light sand and appropriate stain/seal/finish will likely leave you with a very nice looking floor. Questions about _finishing_ the floor would be _on_ topic over at WW.SE

Comment: "*Will that come up well as a wooden floor?*"  What does that mean? What is the  DIY question, the end goal?

Comment: @AlaskaMan "come up well" is a British/Australian phrase meaning, generally, "once processed, will it look good"

Comment: Ha ha, thanks for the banter.  I had a floorboarding specialist come out and they claimed that it would come up well, but there are holes in it where they put in power sockets and the like.  He didn’t talk about what kind of wood it is.  So it would be difficult to get a good finish on it. His suggestion was to lay a new floor over the top of it, which has the added advantage of being able to put an insulating layer between.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-answer:  (Not an answer, but pointers to where you can find one)

- Find the year of construction.
- Find a builder that was active during that era.
- Show him your picture.

---

That said:  It looks like you have damage or rot on one board.  I'm puzzled by the light streak toward the bottom (picture) of many of the boards.

Some softwoods are suitable for flooring.  Larch heartwood works well, as does douglas fir, once it's about 5 years old. Some hardwoods do not work well, either because they are too soft, or don't sand well.

You can check for hardness by getting a sample of wooden flooring from a floor store, and see what height you have to drop a medium size rock on it to produce a dent in the wood.  Now repeat that test with your uncovered floor.  (The actual test is with a spring powered thingy that you snap, and then measure the depth of the ding.)

If the wood is porous you can improve the hardness somewhat with WEST  Wet Epoxy Saturation Technology. This uses a slow cure epoxy that soaks into the pores.  Normally used as a boat construction technique along with thin layers of fiberglass or kevlar.